# Difference of implementations of the SQL standard in different relational database management system (RDBMS)

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset that comparing the difference of implementations of the SQL standard in different relational database management system (RDBMS).

Ideally, it should contain the list of rows such as:

```
SQL feature ID, SQL feature name, SQL feature standard, MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle    
0, CHARACTER_LENGTH, 1992, yes, yes, no
1, FETCH FIRST, 2008, no, yes, no
```

I am aware of some free-text resources such as http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms but I am looking for some more machine-readable format.